# использование websocket

Tags: websocket

Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, какой хостинг нужен, чтобы можно было запустить например, чат, используя протокол websocket? Чтобы сработала команда, типа такой:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://mysite.com:8080");
```

Comment: У меня это сработало, но не знаю правильно ли это:
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

Answer (score 2):

Такое на, котором вы сможете запустить собственное приложение поддерживающее подключения по ws. Апач вроде как умеет ретранслировать ws соединения -  mod_proxy_wstunnel. Соответственно хостинг где есть такой модуль возможно вам подойдет. Но я лично писал отдельные приложения-сервисы.

Answer (score 0):

Для чата идеальный вариант хостинг с node.js.